# Changing Page Viewer Screen Offset

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-button, viewpagerindicator

I want to know how to make the screenoffset for page viewer 0. When I make it 0, it gives a warning message and defaults it to 1. I know this is not possible but is there a way around it. I want to load only one page at a time. This is beacuse I have a button which changes with every page. Since the pages get pre-loaded, the buttons dont change.

Comment: Are you referring to the offscreen page limit?

Comment: Yes that is right. Sorry wasn't clear enough